# How to associate the mailto protocol with a custom exe?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, file-association, protocol

In Windows 8, How do you set the default program for the mailto protocol to a custom exe? Under Default Programs, the only option I get is to select from a list of programs (Mail or Google Chrome) or to "Look for an app in the store". However, I want to associate the mailto protocol with a custom exe.

Answer (score 1):

The following saved as a .REG file, edited to specify my custom EXE and imported into the registry works for me in Windows 7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Path\\to\\Program.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\mailto]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\mailto\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\mailto\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Path\\to\\Program.exe"
```

Remember that your setting can always be overridden by the user via browser options.